# how to swap two table cell value and update into database using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

javascript code

```
$("#table td").click(function () {

    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    var value = $(this).find('td').html();
   // alert(value);
});

$('.swapbutton').on('click', function (e) {
    alert($("#table td.selected td:first").html());
});
```

css

```
  td {
    border: 1px #DDD solid;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
   }

   .selected {
    background-color: brown;
    color: #FFF;
   }
```

[image]

Please see above image

- I want **Swap** two table cell value
- I would like to  get value of selected two cell when click on **Swap button** and swap it

how to do it using JavaScript or Jquery also update into database

Comment: I see 3 selected columns in your screenshot

Comment: Actual I tried my code but i selected more than 2 cell I tried to remove it but not working so I showed in image my current code work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to what I think it is you where looking to do:

If you need more restrictions on the way it works let me know and I would be happy to adjust. But this should act as a good starting point.

```js
$(function() {
  $("table td:not(.notSelectable)").click(function() {
    $(".lastSelected").removeClass("lastSelected");
    $(".selected").toggleClass("selected lastSelected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
});

function swap() {
  // We cannot swap if there are not 2 selected items
  if ($(".selected, .lastSelected").length != 2) { return; }

  // Set label with date data
  $("#lblSelectedDate").text($(".selected").siblings(".date").text());
  $("#lblLastSelectedDate").text($(".lastSelected").siblings(".date").text());

  // Set label with value data
  $("#lblSelectedValue").text($(".selected").children("input[type=hidden]").val());
  $("#lblLastSelectedValue").text($(".lastSelected").children("input[type=hidden]").val());

  // Swap cell data
  var temp = $(".lastSelected").html();
  $(".lastSelected").html($(".selected").html());
  $(".selected").html(temp);
  $(".selected, .lastSelected").removeClass();
}
```

```css
td:not(.notSelectable) {
  cursor: pointer
}

td.selected,
td.lastSelected {
  background-color: maroon;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="swap();">Swap</button>
<br /><br />
Selected Date: <span id="lblSelectedDate"></span>
<br /> Selected Value: <span id="lblSelectedValue"></span>
<br /> Last Selected Date: <span id="lblLastSelectedDate"></span>
<br /> Last Selected Value: <span id="lblLastSelectedValue"></span>
<br /><br />

<table border="solid">
  <thead>
    <th>Date</th><th>First</th><th>Second</th><th>Third</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="notSelectable date">01/01/2018 10:00 pm</td>
      <td>00<input type="hidden" value="00" /></td>
      <td>01<input type="hidden" value="01" /></td>
      <td>02<input type="hidden" value="02" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="notSelectable date">01/01/2018 11:00 pm</td>
      <td>10<input type="hidden" value="10" /></td>
      <td>11<input type="hidden" value="11" /></td>
      <td>12<input type="hidden" value="12" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="notSelectable date">01/01/2018 12:00 pm</td>
      <td>20<input type="hidden" value="20" /></td>
      <td>21<input type="hidden" value="21" /></td>
      <td>22<input type="hidden" value="22" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it works fine thanks  one more things i want to get  when click on swap button date and time of selected row required how to get it?

Comment: @Pravin I have added a date row to the answer and shown how to get the value of it based on both of the selected items.

Comment: swap cell value work fine small thing if want to pass id of respective cell value to my ajax function which stored in hidden field in the cell how to do it?

Comment: @Pravin I have added the extra hidden fields you asked for and shown how to access them. Please take the time to update your question to reflect the answer I am giving.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = [];
var tdObj = [];
$("#table td").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    for(var i=0; i<2;i++) {
        tdObj[i] = $(this).find('td');
        value[i] = tdObj.text();
        if(i>1) return false;
    }
    // alert(value);
});

$('.swapbutton').on('click', function (e) {
    for(var i=2; i>0;i--) {
        value[i] = tdObj[i].text();
    }
});
```

Comment: add demo in jsfiddle for test